# joining text file with cat and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cat

so, i have two text file containing

```
title1
title2
```

stored in `title.txt`

and

```
data1
data2
```

stored in `data.txt`

and i'd like to join it with `cat`, so it gonna look like this

```
title1 | data1
title2 | data2
```

but, the regular `cat title.txt data.txt > out.txt` turns the out.txt file into

```
title1
title2
data1
data2
```

i need help on using the `cat` so the file can look like this:

```
title1 | data1
title2 | data2
```

any answer will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try saying:

```
paste -d'|' title.txt data.txt
```

For your input, it should return:

```
title1|data1
title2|data2
```

Comment: @user1072976 Did you try `paste -d'|' file1 file2 file3`?

Comment: i tried it, it works, but, howeverm it leaves another line containing " | | "

ex: title1|data1
      |  |

Comment: @user1072976 That's because you have extra blank lines in the input files.

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop to read from both

```
while IFS= read -r line && IFS= read -r line1 <&3;
     do         
        title=`echo -ne $line`;
        data=`echo -ne "$line1"`;
        echo "$title | $data" > output.txt              
     done <data.txt" 3<title.txt"
```